# Serializing git commits and sending them via REST

Tags: git, gitolite

I have for example 3 machines with same git repo. And I also have DMZs between pairs of machines, DMZ here being internal network without external access, *machine B* only has access two both DMZs and as such needs to server as conduit between *machine A* and *machine C*.

All machines have *gitolite* installed (for the sake of clarity). I need to bring *pull* data from machine C to machine A.

[image]

My idea is to have machines **B** pull code from **C**, serialize that data and send it via REST to machine **A**.

And somehow I need to use deserialized that to encorporate those commits to machine **A**'s repo. Thous emulating pull from machine **C** to **A** machine. Hope that this makes sense and does anybody have idea how to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why use REST for that?

I would just have a bare repo on **B** and let **A** fetch from **B** and **B** fetch from **C**. If you have ssh access to **B**, you can even make **B** pull while sitting at **A**.

OR

I don't know if that is possible, but you could make **B** create a ssh tunnel from **A** to **C**. That way you could simply fetch directly from **C**.

Answer (score 0):

I do that with a gitolite user in `B` which (in a cron job):

- pull from `C/master`
- push to A in a dedicated branch `master_C`

That gitolite user has special read-write access to the relevant repos (read in gitolite `C`, write in gitolite `A`).

The dedicated branch `master_C` on `A` allows me to always push successfully (it is always a fast-forward push).
The user is then in charge of monitoring that branch and merge it when appropriate to his/her `master` branch of `A`.